# Can insufficient memory or CPU time cause a Node app to restart?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a Node/Express app with a Nginx front-end in a 512MB AWS LightSail instance (small slice of a CPU).

99% of the time it runs fine. However, when I am doing `apt-get update`, sometimes, the web app becomes non-responsive and a web request during this time will eventually see the Nginx 502 bad gateway page. When this happens, most of the time, the Node app will restart, with no error messages, before `apt-get update` runs to completion.

When `apt-get update` is running, I observe that `kwapd0` appears at the top of `top` rather often.

What could be causing this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Insufficient memory can cause any program to terminate because the Out Of Memory manager will kill a process to keep the system running. On a VM with 512MB of RAM, node would definitely be the largest process, and would be at the top of the list to be killed to make more memory available. The error message for this would be in the system logs, because it's the system terminating the program.

Use a larger VM or add a swap file (at least 2gb, but maybe larger depending on your node app) and the problem will likely go away.

Insufficient CPU can cause Nginx to timeout when connecting to the node app if the node app can't respond quickly enough. But I would expect a 504   Gateway Timeout error if that happened.